# how to use codeigniter to upload image to azure blob storage?

Tags: php, codeigniter, azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I want to use codeigniter to upload image to azure blob storage.

I search this library 
https://github.com/thomasantony/codeigniter-azure/

but i don't know how to use the azure-php library

can someone help ? thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer:

```
$this->load->library('azure');

$blob_storage = $this->azure->get_blob_storage();

var_dump($blob_storage -> listBlobs("xxx-container-name-xxx"));
```

doc check - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php