# Azure blob storage integration with codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to access `microsoft azure blob storage` through codeigniter3 . I took files from
[codeigniter-azure](https://github.com/thomasantony/codeigniter-azure) and followed the process. I copied the files within the libraries folder to my application/libraries folder and I also added azure `account_name,account_key` in application/config/config.php file.

I written code in my controller.

```
$this->load->library('azure');
$blob_storage = $this->azure->get_blob_storage();
var_dump($blob_storage -> listBlobs("xxx-container-name-xxx"));
```

When I am executing code then I am getting error `Call to a member function get_blob_storage() on null`.

Comment: Hi Nirdesh, seems your issue has been solved, so could you pls accept my answer to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to list blobs under a container or some directory, you can easily generate a [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#sas-token) and then use [Azure blob rest APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) to do this.
For how to generate a SAS token and call the rest API, just see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64965301/codeigniter3-listing-all-directory-and-files-from-azure-blob-storage/67781633#67781633).
It does not involve any other libs I think it should be a workaround here.